# Collecting emails on a static page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

I have a static page on my Rails 3.1 site. I have a Visitor model that has only an email attribute (email:string). I would like to collect emails from visitors to my site. They will type their email in a text field and click on submit and then be redirect to a thank you page.

I can do this sort of thing with resources but I don't need that much. Just a submit and a thank you.

How do I do this? Please provide code for the view and the controller.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong about using resources? Your visitor is a resource, so why not treat it like one?

In your routes:

```
resource :visitors, :only => :create # POST to visitor_path to create a visitor
root_to ...
```

In the VisitorController

```
def create
  @visitor = Visitor.new(params[:visitor])
  if @visitor.save
    render "pages/comingsoon" # or redirect, or render leave empty to render views/visitors/create.html.erb
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

Now you can have a file views/pages/comingsoon.html.erb with content

```
<h1>Thank you</h1>
<p>Stored your email address <%= @visitor.email %></p>
```

And for completeness, the form for a new visitor:

```
<%= form_for Visitor.new do |f| => ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but don't understand how the form_for or form_tag work. What will the form look like in the static page where I collect the email? Also, don't I have to redirect_to thankyou.html if @visitor.save in the VisitorController?

Comment: <%= form_for Visitor.new do |f| %> should do. Yes, you can also redirect_to "thankyou", but you would lose the ability to render the email of the current user with @visitor.email in the thankyou page.

Comment: Thanks. So now when I submit the form it successfully takes the email but redirects me to localhost:3000/visitors and gives me the message "Template is missing" referring to the "create". How do I get it to thankyou.html.haml? Also, isn't it "resources :visitors"?

Comment: You will always only have a singular visitor, that's why I used resource. If you want to add e.g. an index action later on, you should go for resources, yes. Regarding the template issue: either create the template views/visitor/create.html.erb as described in my answer, or redirect to your thankyou page (e.g. redirect_to "www.example.com/thankyou").

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'm new to Rails. Your suggestion is good, only prob is when I add "resource :visitor, :only => :create" and I have "root :to => 'pages#comingsoon'" in routes I get "Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"visitors", :format=>nil}" even though I do have a visitors controller with a create action. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry this is becoming such a long discussion. Could you please try with `resources :visitors, :only => :create` in your routes?